# "I am too picky when it comes to food" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I say 'I am too picky when it comes to food' in Spanish?

Comment: When asking for a translation, you should provide your own attempt to translate the phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd translate it as: "Soy muy quisquilloso cuando se trata de comida".